# R - Recode NA with levels of a factor in grouped data

Tags: r, na, recode

I have a data frame with a longitudinal structure as follows:

```
df = structure(list(oslaua = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("E06000001", "E06000002", 
 "E06000003", "E06000004"), class = "factor"), wave = structure(c(1L, 
 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("0", 
 "1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), old.la = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
 NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, NA), .Label = c("00EB", 
 "00EC", "00EE", "00EF"), class = "factor"), la = structure(c(1L, 
 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, NA), .Label = c("Hartlepool UA", 
 "Middlesbrough UA", "Redcar and Cleveland UA", "Stockton-on-Tees UA"
 ), class = "factor"), dclg.code = structure(c(1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 
 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("H0724", 
 "H0738", "V0728", "W0734"), class = "factor"), novo_entries = c(24L, 
 4L, 0L, 1L, 35L, 15L, 1L, 0L, 49L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 40L, 14L, 0L)), .Names = c("oslaua", 
 "wave", "old.la", "la", "dclg.code", "novo_entries"), row.names = c(NA, 
 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

My identifier variable is `oslaua` and my time variable is `wave`. `old.la`, `la` and `dclg.code` are factor variables that have NA. My 
  goal consists of recoding my `NA` by with the level of each variable associated with each identifier (`oslaua`). I have tried to do this for the case of `old.la` using the following:

```
df = df %>% group_by(oslaua) %>% mutate(old.la.1 = ifelse(is.na(old.la), unique(old.la), old.la)) %>% as.data.frame()
```

I partially get my purpose but there are some issues as you can see:

```
> df
      oslaua wave old.la                      la dclg.code novo_entries old.la.1
1  E06000001    0   00EB           Hartlepool UA     H0724           24        1
2  E06000001    1   00EB           Hartlepool UA     H0724            4        1
3  E06000001    2   <NA>                    <NA>      <NA>            0        2
4  E06000001    3   00EB           Hartlepool UA     H0724            1        1
5  E06000002    0   00EC        Middlesbrough UA     W0734           35        2
6  E06000002    1   00EC        Middlesbrough UA     W0734           15        2
7  E06000002    2   00EC        Middlesbrough UA     W0734            1        2
8  E06000002    3   <NA>                    <NA>      <NA>            0        2
9  E06000003    0   00EE Redcar and Cleveland UA     V0728           49        3
10 E06000003    1   00EE Redcar and Cleveland UA     V0728            7        3
11 E06000003    2   00EE Redcar and Cleveland UA     V0728            2        3
12 E06000003    3   00EE Redcar and Cleveland UA     V0728            2        3
13 E06000004    0   00EF     Stockton-on-Tees UA     H0738           40        4
14 E06000004    1   00EF     Stockton-on-Tees UA     H0738           14        4
15 E06000004    2   <NA>                    <NA>      <NA>            0        4
```

Concretely, the levels of the factors change their format and also in some cases the observations are recoded wrongly (e.g.`oslaua = E06000001` -  row 3)

I do not understand why the levels change their format and how I could keep their original (alphanumeric) format. Also, why some observations are not recoded properly.

Any suggestion to address those is really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, old.la1 := levels(droplevels(old.la)), by = oslaua]
```

---

For multiple columns

```
nm1 <-  c("old.la", "la", "dclg.code")
df1 <-  setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) levels(droplevels(x))[1]) , 
       by = oslaua, .SDcols = nm1][df,  on = "oslaua"]
df1[, !grepl("i\\.", names(df1)), with = FALSE]
```

Our initial idea was

```
setDT(df)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
     factor(levels(droplevels(x)))) , by = oslaua, .SDcols = nm1]
```

But for some reason, converting to `factor` within each group gets some weird output having only a single level for each column in the output (using v1.10.0)

Comment: Many thanks @akrun, that´s exactly what I need. I still do not get why it changed the format of the factor when I was applying my solution.

Comment: @Edu It changed to `character`, but after the `df1`, you can reconvert the columns to `factor` i.e. `df2 <- df1[, !grepl("i\\.", names(df1)), with = FALSE]; df2[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, factor), .SDcols = nm1]`

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
library(zoo)

df %>%
  group_by(oslaua) %>%
  mutate(old.la.1 = na.locf(old.la))
```

It uses `zoo`'s last one carried forward function to replace the NA's.  It's type safe.  In your code, `ifelse` is constructing two vectors (one for the case where the test resolves to `TRUE`, the other for when it resolves to `FALSE`.  To ensure compatibility, it seems that `ifelse` reduces each of those to the most basic, common type.  In the case of factors, this is an integer (run `typeof(df$old.la)`.

Comment: This only works if the NA value is never the first of its group, no?

Comment: You are correct.  This could be mitigated using `arrange` (forcing `NA` to the end), but probably not the ideal solution.  akrun's solution could be implemented in the `dplyr` framework just as well.

Comment: This could be fixed by using `na.aggregate` instead of `na.locf` .

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, a more elegant solution that avoids creating new variables would be using `fill()` from `tidyr`:

```
data = data %>% group_by(oslaua) %>% fill(old.la, la, dclg.code)
data
```

Which yields:

```
> data
Source: local data frame [15 x 6]
Groups: oslaua [4]

      oslaua   wave old.la                      la dclg.code novo_entries
      <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>                  <fctr>    <fctr>        <int>
1  E06000001      0   00EB           Hartlepool UA     H0724           24
2  E06000001      1   00EB           Hartlepool UA     H0724            4
3  E06000001      2   00EB           Hartlepool UA     H0724            0
4  E06000001      3   00EB           Hartlepool UA     H0724            1
5  E06000002      0   00EC        Middlesbrough UA     W0734           35
6  E06000002      1   00EC        Middlesbrough UA     W0734           15
7  E06000002      2   00EC        Middlesbrough UA     W0734            1
8  E06000002      3   00EC        Middlesbrough UA     W0734            0
9  E06000003      0   00EE Redcar and Cleveland UA     V0728           49
10 E06000003      1   00EE Redcar and Cleveland UA     V0728            7
11 E06000003      2   00EE Redcar and Cleveland UA     V0728            2
12 E06000003      3   00EE Redcar and Cleveland UA     V0728            2
13 E06000004      0   00EF     Stockton-on-Tees UA     H0738           40
14 E06000004      1   00EF     Stockton-on-Tees UA     H0738           14
15 E06000004      2   00EF     Stockton-on-Tees UA     H0738            0
```